# Problems debugging using Cygwin gdb in Eclipse CDT(Helios)

Tags: gdb, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to debug an application using Eclipse CDT and cygwin gdb and I am facing a problem if my code calls `Sleep()`, it looks like whenever a sleep is encountered in the code the debugger seems to go in an infinite loop(***I meant it never terminates or hit a breakpoint after sleep)***.
On pressing pause the code is stuck on one of the thread on **`sigint::interrupt`**.
Even my debugger console windows throw these error in the console output:

```
[New thread 5968.0x1f98]
Error: dll starting at 0x774a0000 not found.
Error: dll starting at 0x775c0000 not found.
[New thread 5968.0x19e8]
```

Any idea what are these errors about?

It would be helpful if someone can help me out here as I am new to eclipse and I am used to using VS so it has made be lazy to be honest and expect things to work out of box.

Here are more details if required

- Windows 7 x64 bit.
- Eclipse 3.6 Helios with CDT plug-in compiled from the CVS head.
- Cygwin latest from website, I think it is 1.71

Answer (score 0):

There are a [few threads](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/cdt-dev/msg13901.html) in [this issue](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.cdt/msg17658.html), but there aren't many.
Probably because it is not so much a CDT problem, but rather a [gdb issue](http://dev.omnetpp.org/bugs/view.php?id=143).

So you need to compare the exact gdb version used with the ones involved in [gdb bugs database](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/), which you can [browse here](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/).

For instance, there is this [**critical** bug 11031](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11031) "gdb terminates when trying to set breakpoint at C++ exception", which may be related (but unresolved).

Comment: thanks VonC I replaced the my gdb 6.8 with ver 7.0 and it seems to work now but the it seems quite temperamental. Couple of times it didn't terminate but most of times it works perfectly.

Comment: But I still get the following error.Any clue what do these error mean 

[New thread 5968.0x1f98]

Error: dll starting at 0x774a0000 not found.

Error: dll starting at 0x775c0000 not found.

[New thread 5968.0x19e8

Comment: @Rohan: no direct clue. From there, this is really linked to your specific environment (like in this thread - http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=391 - where users where running a Windows 64bits through a VM). This is not your case, but you must have some special configuration of your own which is not compatible with gdb.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by installing GDB 7.1. Older versions of GDB doesn't seems to be supporting 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to gdb 7.2 and and get the following error in the cdt console:

Error: dll starting at 0x76e30000 not found.
Error: dll starting at 0x76090000 not found.
Error: dll starting at 0x76e30000 not found.
Error: dll starting at 0x76f50000 not found.

I am also using Windows 7 64 bits and the latest Cygwin. I tried the debugger in a normal shell and it worked fine. I could debug my application.